# Error while creating CNAME Record for Hosted

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I am new to amazon aws and creating record for hosted zone ,but while creating CNAME i am encountering following error :

```
Error occurred
Bad request.
(InvalidChangeBatch 400: RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name www.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.in is not permitted as it creates a CNAME or alias loop in the zone.
```

i was able to create A,NS and SOA record for my hosted zone ,Can anyone please help me resolve the issue

Comment: The error is telling you that you are creating a CNAME that points back to itself, which is not a valid CNAME.

Comment: @MarkB How shall i resolve this , what should i insert into record name and value for it?

Comment: Given the limited amount of information you have provided, I really have no idea what you are trying to do. I tried to help you interpret the error message, but you need to look at what you are doing and figure out why Route53 thinks you are creating a record that references itself.